# Codeigniter 3 - how to remove the function name from URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

My URL is:

```
example.com/controller/function/parameter
=> example.com/category/index/category_name
```

I need:

```
example.com/category/category_name
```

I have tried several solutions provided by Stackoverflow questions asked on this, but it´s not working. Either it redirects to home or a `404 page not found`.

The options I have tried are:

```
$route['category'] = "category/index"; //1

$route['category/(:any)'] = "category/index"; //2

$route['category/(:any)'] = "category/index/$1";  //3
```

Another route is:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
```

The htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

In config file I have:

```
$config['url_suffix'] = '';
```

Comment: `$route['category/(:any)'] = "category/index/$1";  //3` this must work fine. I have tried it. And getting correct response

Comment: i think you just need route #3.  
can you show your category controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have error in your `.htaccess` file. Please find below code for `.htaccess` file.

You can use `RewriteBase` to provide a base for your rewrites.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /campnew/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

In Controller your method.

```
public function index($category_name = null) {
    $this->load->model('category_model');

    $data = array();

    if ($query = $this->category_model->get_records_view($category_name)) {
        $data['recordss'] = $query;
    }
    if ($query2 = $this->category_model->get_records_view2($category_name)) 
    {
        $data['recordsc2'] = $query2;
    }

    $data['main_content'] = 'category';
    $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
}
```

In Model File

```
public function get_records_view($category){
    $this->db->where('a.linkname', $category); 
}
```

Let me know if it not works.

Comment: it still redirects to the home page

Comment: Have you added  `$route['category/(:any)'] = "category/index/$1";` line in your `config/routs.php` file.?

Comment: Also how you are passing parameters in your model function..? I can not see it in your controller function.

Comment: In model function using where('a.linkname', $this->uri->segment(3));  to get the related details from db & show products in view-page coming under that category

Comment: Lets discuss on chat : https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148714/https-stackoverflow-com-questions-44993162-codeigniter-3-remove-function-name-f

Comment: it needs 20 reputation to discuss on chat, & I am new here... can we chat on fb, my id - chetan.bns

Comment: @ChetanDeora: Glad to help you out from this hurdle, Let me know ig you need any other help

Comment: Not at all dear, We are here to help eachother

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why you couldn't get it to work.

Here is some test code I created to check this out...
This is using CI 3.1.5.

**.htaccess** - same as what you have...

**Controller - Category.php**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Category extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index($category_name = 'None Selected') {
        echo "The Category name is " . $category_name;
    }
}
```

**routes.php**

```
$route['category/(:any)'] = "category/index/$1";  //3 - this works

$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

**Test URLS**

`/category/` **output:** `The Category name is None Selected`

`/category/fluffy-bunnies` **output:**  `The Category name is fluffy-bunnies`

Have a play with that and see if you can find the issue.

Comment: localhost/campnew/category/garden-tents-2380 
takes to home page... 

While link http://localhost/campnew/category/index/garden-tents-2380
displays "The Category name is garden-tents-2380 " on top of the page

Comment: @TimBrownlaw Default routes should be first ones but also when ever you have some kind of wild card placeholder, it should go at most end line applicable.

Comment: @Tpojka ideally yes. I just put it at the top to make it stick out a bit more and to ensure it got first go when testing... Remember it is just Debug/test code...

Comment: I can (or you too) notice it on first look. I am just telling that proposed code should be given in a way like there is no chance for producing other eventual errors (not explicitly nor implicitly) tied to first problem.